# How to display an image stored in Mysql database with special date not by id (php)

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I am trying to display an image uploaded to my "upload" table in MySql. I've been reading a lot on how to do this but no luck.

"news_content" table is for uploading NEWS content to Mysql and has 6 columns: id,title, description, content_text, date, time

and "upload" table has 5 columns: id, name, size, image, date

In "news_content" table I upload the date and the time columns separately but the date column in "upload" table is a string concatenated with both date and time. For example if in "news_content" table the date is 2/3/2016 and the time is 5:30, in "upload" table the date is going to be 2/3/20165:30. I organized it that way in order to retrieve the image by its specific date and time that the related post uploaded.

I upload the image in *news.php* page with this following code:

**news.php :**

```
// Create connection
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","p206405az");

// Check connection
if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//select a database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db( "news" , $connection) ;
    if (!$db_select) { die("Selection faild:" . mysql_error())  ;
}
//uploading the content of news and date and time
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $title = $_POST["title"] ;
    $description = $_POST["description"] ;
    $content_text  =  $_POST["content_text"]  ;
    $date = $_POST["date"] ;
    $time = $_POST["time"] ;
//perform mysql query
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news_content (title, description, content_text, date, time)
        VALUES ('$title', '$description', '$content_text' ,'$date' , '$time' )")  ;

    if (!$result) {
        die("Insert failed: " . mysql_error());
        $submitMessage = "Problem with updating the post, please try again" ;

    } else if ($result){

        $submitMessage = "Your post succsessfully updated" ;
    }

}
// uploading the image
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0)
{
    $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $filedate = "$date" . "$time" ;

    $fp       = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content2 = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content3 = addslashes($content2);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, image, date ) ".
        "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content3', '$filedate')";

    mysql_query($query) or die('Error2, query failed');
}
```

And I want to retrieve that image by *getImage.php* page to use it as source page later by this following code but it seems it can't retrieve the blob data:

P.S. The image is successfully uploaded but I can't retrieve it with specific date that I Posted lately

**getImage.php :**

```
// Create connection
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","p206405az");

// Check connection
if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//select a database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db( "news" , $connection) ;
if (!$db_select) { die("Selection faild:" . mysql_error())  ;
}

//perform mysql query

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news_content" , $connection);
if (!$result) {
    die("read failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//useing returned data
while ($content = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $date = $content["date"];
    $time = $content["time"] ;

}

$filedate = "$date" . "$time" ;

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM upload WHERE date='$filedate'" , $connection);
if (!$result2) {
    die("read failed: " . mysql_error());
};

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
mysql_close($connection);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['image'];
```

And I want to display the image in *index.php* page with this following HTML code:

**index.php :**

```
<img src="getImage.php?date=<?php echo $filedate ; ?>" width="175" height="200" />
```

How can I retrieve that data in *getImage.php* page and then use that page az source page to display the image in *index.php* page?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What errors you get?

Comment: @fusion3k Nothing. That's the problem. It just doesn't show the image but a broken image sign.

Comment: get image directly by url (not in `<img>` tag) and comment `header()` command to see errors.

Comment: @fusion3k sry can you give me an example how?(in code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cant figure out the error unless php throws an error. but i would save the images as files instead of db and keep its name if news table's row, unless there are multiple images per news.

in case of multimple image per news, i would just match the image id to news id.

schema for news.db

```
id, title, description, content_text, date, time
```

schema for upload.db:

```
id, image, newsid
```

my image html link would have been:

```
<img src="getImage.php?id=<?php echo $newsid; ?>" width="175" height="200" />
```

and then my getimage.php would have been like this:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","p206405az");
if (!$connection) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error());
 }
 $db_select = mysql_select_db( "images" , $connection) ;
 if (!$db_select) { 
   die("Selection faild:" . mysql_error())  ;
 }
 $id=$_GET["id"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM upload WHERE newsid='$id' LIMIT 1" , $connection);
if (!$result) {
   die("read failed: " . mysql_error());
};

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_close($connection);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print $row['image'];
```

Comment: What is $_GET["id] do here? is it get table's id? What if I want to get another row by lets say date column and not the id, What should I do instead? and another question is what if I have 3 tables in a db,which table's id $_GET["id"] get? the id of first table or the second one or the third one?

Comment: It is my proposed solution in a scenario similar to yours. see the code for image html link above. it will ask for particular image from database having images (upload Table). Then the getimage.php will return that image (from upload table) to display in html.

Answer (score 0):

To show errors:

1. add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at top of your page;
2. temporarily comment the header line: `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");`;
3. retrieve image directly from browser address bar (see image below);
4. If you obtain a “500 Server Error” check your Apache error log (compile errors are not displayed even with error_reporting enabled);

[image]

Comment: it only gives me this error:  The image "http://localhost:89/-C/wamp/www/news/getImage.php?date=2/13/201603:19:19am" cannot be displayed because it contains errors. should I set the date column as primary key?

Comment: 1) Using slashes as separator is not a good idea; 2) you have commented the `header` line? Comment also following line to see if **text** is printed out **before** image

Comment: please also check the value of `$filedate` variable: are you sure that it match `date` db field? if `date` field is datetime format, I think probably it doesn't match. Also: you ask for a specific image, but where in your code process the `date` passed by url?